# Python one-liner to get a combined list of all values of a list of Enum classes

Tags: python, list, enums, list-comprehension

I have 2 Enum classes defined as below:

```
class Enum1(Enum):
    V1 = 'v1'
    V2 = 'v2'

class Enum2(Enum):
   V1 = 'v1'
   V2 = 'v2'
```

I want a combine list of all the values in both Enum1 and Enum2. I currently do it this way:

```
enumList([Enum1, Enum2])

def enumList(Enums):
    l = []
    for E in Enums:
        l += list(map(lambda e: e, E))
    return  l
```

Running this, I get:

```
[<Enum1.V1: 'v1'>, <Enum1.V2: 'v2'>, <Enum2.V1: 'v1'>, <Enum2.V2: 'v2'>]
```

Is there a one-liner `enumList` implementation that achieves the same?

**My attempt**:

```
def enumList(Enums):
    return sum([list(map(lambda e: e, E)) for E in Enums], [])
```

Comment: `[j for E in Enums for j in map(lambda e: e, E)]`?

Comment: There's nothing special about `Enum` here, it's the same logic and syntax as any other conversion of a for loop to a comprehension/map construct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `map` seems unnecessary.

You can use a list comprehension with a nested `for`:

```
combined_list = [e for et in [Enum1, Enum2] for e in et]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import chain
combined = list(chain(Enum1, Enum2)) # [<Enum1.V1: 'v1'>, <Enum1.V2: 'v2'>, <Enum2.V1: 'v1'>, <Enum2.V2: 'v2'>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*map(lambda e: e, [Enum1, Enum2])))
```